# Class 'Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Document\Generic' is not a valid document or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, symfony-cmf

hi everyone  i am new to symfony2 cmf 
i have success fully installed the cmf to my local system and it run suceessfully 
but my problem is when i deploy it ti my server it gives following error

**error**

```
Class 'Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Document\Generic' is not a valid document or mapped super class
```

.

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Mapping\MappingException: "Class 'Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Document\Generic' is not a valid document or mapped super class." at /home/mahavl5z/public_html/mahaveer/cmf-sandbox1/vendor/doctrine/phpcr-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/PHPCR/Mapping/MappingException.php line 53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your application runs in the "prod" environment (that is, not going through app_dev.php) you need to make sure the cache is up to date.

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

for performance reason, symfony skips a lot of checks in prod mode.

if this does not fix the issue, check if "prod" works locally and if you miss something when deploying.

as I don't get notifications on disucssions here, please open an issue on the relevant github project if you have further questions.

Comment: I typed `php app/console cache:clear` but all it says is, "Could not open input file: app/console". Why?

Comment: This sounds like your installation is incomplete. there should be a php file at app/console. (you need to run the command from the root of your web installation - or specify the full path to the console script, that works as well)